# How can I set Accessibility Identifier for all the subviews of a view in (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]I'm creating a shared alert for all screens. Code below:

```
let window: UIWindow = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! 
AppDelegate).window!
let view = UIView(frame: window.bounds)
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 
21))
view.accessibilityIdentifier = "view"
window.addsubview(view)
```

When i was trying to identify the view accessibility identifier in the XCode accessibility identifier tool, I wasn't able to get the identifier name.

Can anyone help out? How can i get the identifier name of the view?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As i understand you have issue window as well so get and use the first window  below :

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
```

With a accessibility identifier tool, you should see the subelements of the Window as below :

[image]